# Power Bi - Display Trend line for a Year - Quarter Graph (Clustered Column Chart)

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I am able to get the Trend line when there is only Year on the axis. But, I want the trend line when there is a quarter as well.

I am not sure if the solution for this requirement is Possible with Power BI. I don't think it is possible at the moment. But, putting it here as someone might have a workaround for this.

This is my data for this example,

```
Date Category   Value
1/1/2018    A   4
2/1/2018    A   7
3/1/2018    A   6
4/1/2018    A   1
5/1/2018    A   8
6/1/2018    A   1
7/1/2018    A   7
8/1/2018    A   1
9/1/2018    A   9
10/1/2018   A   10
11/1/2018   A   2
12/1/2018   A   1
1/1/2019    A   7
2/1/2019    A   1
3/1/2019    A   4
1/1/2018    B   10
2/1/2018    B   1
3/1/2018    B   7
4/1/2018    B   4
5/1/2018    B   8
6/1/2018    B   4
7/1/2018    B   7
8/1/2018    B   9
9/1/2018    B   10
10/1/2018   B   10
11/1/2018   B   7
12/1/2018   B   5
1/1/2019    B   4
2/1/2019    B   4
3/1/2019    B   1
```

[image: Trend Line]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using a Line and Clustered Column chart type.

[image: Lines and Bars]

For the lines, you'll need to define measures like this:

```
A Line = CALCULATE(SUM(Table2[Value]), Table2[Category] = "A")
B Line = CALCULATE(SUM(Table2[Value]), Table2[Category] = "B")
```

Comment: But what I have is a trend line. I think that is different from the line chart...

Comment: Right. It's a workaround. If you want the lines to show a linear trend for each series, then you'll need to define the measures appropriately, but it is possible.

Comment: can you please help me with this -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55935908/power-bi-measure-dax-concatenation-and-contains-to-find-the-matching